# Is this an inconsistency in the pnpm docs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pnpm

**Background**

Reading the pnpm docs, we find the following paragraph in the [Node-Modules configuration options with pnpm](https://www.pnpm.cn/blog/2020/10/17/node-modules-configuration-options-with-pnpm) article:

> By default, pnpm v5 will create a semi-strict node_modules. Semi-strict means that your application will only be able to require packages that are added as dependencies to package.json (with a few exceptions). **However, your dependencies will be able to access any packages.**
>
> The default configuration looks like this:
>
> All packages are hoisted to **node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules**:
> `hoist-pattern[]=*`
>
> All types are hoisted to the root in order to make TypeScript happy: `public-hoist-pattern[]=*types*`
>
> All ESLint-related packages are hoisted to the root as well: `public-hoist-pattern[]=*eslint*`

However, in all other articles I have read, including [Symlinked `node_modules` structure](https://pnpm.io/symlinked-node-modules-structure), it is stated that the folder structure is as follows:

[image]

In other words, there is no `node_modules` folder directly below `node_modules/.pnpm`, as stated in the first article above (see second bold section).

---

**Question**

1. Is that an error in the docs? If so, which of the two is correct?
2. If there is no node_modules below `.pnpm`, how can it be true that indirect dependencies can access any module in the virtual store (`node_modules/.pnpm`)? For example, in the above image, I do not see how `qar` can access `bar` if `qar` tries to import `bar` without listing it in its dependencies. node will first search the innermost node_modules, then the next one up is the outermost node_modules, which only contains the app's direct dependencies.

Comment: I think I got it. The image above is missing a node_modules folder which contains symlinks to all the packages in the virtual store. So indeed, by default, pnpn includes this folder: `node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules`. It is `hoist=true/false` that controls this behavior.

Comment: I suggest that you write an answer to your own question, so that this question has the status "answered".

Answer (score 0):

The reason all dependencies can access all other packages by default in pnpm, is that pnpm places a `node_modules` inside the virtual store, which symlinks to all the packages in the virtual store:

`node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules/<symlinksToAllPackagesInVirtualStore>`

In other words, the image in the question above is missing a `node_modules` folder.

It is `hoist=true/false` that controls whether or not to create that folder. If `hoist=false`, dependencies can only access their own direct dependencies (similar to the default for the end user application).

---

**LINKS**

- [hoist](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#hoist)
- [hoist-pattern](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#hoist-pattern)
- [public-hoist-pattern](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#public-hoist-pattern)
- [node-linker](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#node-linker)

**COMMENTS**

The concepts linked above could have used better explanations in the docs.

First of all, hoisting means "moving" a package, either by moving the actual files or by creating a symlink to them.

Secondly, there are two types of hoisting done in pnpm.

The first type, controlled by either `public-hoist-pattern`, `shamefully-hoist`, or `node-linker`, refers to whether packages are moved up to the root node_modules. `node-linker: hoisted` will move all packages up, and thus create a flat `node_modules` structure, similar to what npm and yarn does. `shamefully-hoist` is seemingly similar, except it symlinks those packages in the root `node_modules` to the virtual store, instead of actually moving them. At least I think that is what it does. The documentation is lacking here.

The second type of hoisting, is hoisting into a `node_modules` subfolder of the virtual store (`node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules`). In this case, no packages are moved, they still stay in the virtual store (`node_modules/.pnpm`), but symlinks to them are placed in that `node_modules` subfolder. This is what enables all dependencies to access all other packages installed.

As mentioned, pnpm only allows such "unlisted" access by default for dependencies of the end user application. The end-user application itself can only access its direct dependencies. That is one of the benefits of pnpm (in npm and yarn, every package can access every other package, due to the flat node_modules they create). It is pnpm's folder structure and symlinking that enables this behavior. Read the [blog articles](https://pnpm.io/blog) for more insight.

---

**NOTE**

If a pnpm maintainer sees this, I suggest updating the docs with a proper folder structure image. It is not easily understood, the way it now stands.

Comment: @ZoltanKochan If you see this, perhaps add some of these points to the docs?